# HTML Treeview Code with JS for Search

Tags: html

I'm reaching out to share a recent project I've been working on – an HTML Treeview code with JavaScript integration for search functionality. This code enables users to search through the tree structure, with filtering capabilities that dynamically refine the tree as the search progresses.

I've invested time and effort into crafting this functionality, and now I'm eager to gather feedback from peers and experts like yourself. Your insights and suggestions would be invaluable in refining and improving the code further.

Would you be willing to spare some time to review the code and share your thoughts? Your expertise in this area would be greatly appreciated, and your feedback could significantly enhance the usability and effectiveness of this feature.

Thank you in advance for considering my request.

**https://jsfiddle.net/xpz42bLf/**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Tree View Example</title>
<style>
    .treeView {
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        padding-top:28px;
        padding-right:10px;
        padding-left:10px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }
    
    .searchBar{
        margin: 0px;
         position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
         background-color: #f4f4f4;
         padding: 4px;
         display: flex;
    }
    
    #searchInput {
        padding: 4px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    
.treeView details {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
 
.treeView summary {
    padding: 5px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}
 
.treeView summary:hover {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}
 
     .hiddenSummaryArrow::-webkit-details-marker {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .hiddenSummaryArrow {
        list-style: none;
        text-indent: 15px;
    }
    
    .treeViewButtonStyle {
        background: none;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: 500; 
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    }
    
    .treeViewButtonStyle:hover {
        background-color: whitesmoke;
    }
    
</style>
</head>
 
    <div class="searchBar">
<input type="text" id="searchInput" onkeyup="findAndSelectItem()" placeholder="Search...">
</div>
 
 <div class="treeView">
<details>
    <summary>Chapter 1</summary>
    <details>
        <summary>Section 1</summary>
        <details><summary>Paragraph 1</summary></details>
        <details><summary>Paragraph 2</summary></details>
        <details><summary>Paragraph 3</summary></details>
    </details>
    <details><summary>Section 2</summary>
        <details><summary>Paragraph 1</summary></details>
        <details><summary>Paragraph 2</summary></details>
        <details><summary>Paragraph 3</summary></details>
    </details>
    <details><summary>Section 3</summary></details>        
</details>
<details>
    <summary>Chapter 2</summary>
    <details><summary>Section 1</summary></details>
    <details><summary>Section 2</summary></details>
    <details><summary>Section 3</summary></details>
</details>
<details>
    <summary>Chapter 3</summary>
    <details><summary>Section 1</summary></details>
    <details><summary>Section 2</summary></details>
    <details><summary>Section 3</summary></details>        
</details>
</div>
 
 
<script>
 
var summaries = document.querySelectorAll('summary');
summaries.forEach(function(summary) {
    var details = summary.parentNode;
    if (details && details.children.length === 1) {
        summary.classList.add('hiddenSummaryArrow');
    }
});
 
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('summary');
buttons.forEach(function(button) {        
    // Create a button element
    var newButton = document.createElement("button");
    newButton.textContent = button.textContent;
    newButton.classList.add('treeViewButtonStyle');
 
    // Add event listener to the button
    newButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert("Button clicked!");
    });
 
    // Append the button inside the summary
    button.innerHTML = "";       
    button.appendChild(newButton);
});
 
function findAndSelectItem() {
    var input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
    var filter = input.value.trim().toUpperCase();
    var details = document.querySelectorAll("details");
    var firstMatchFound = false;
    
    // Collapse all details if filter is empty
    if (filter === "") {
         for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
        details[i].open = false;
        var summary = details[i].querySelector("summary");
        summary.style.background = '';
    }
        return; // Exit function
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
        var summary = details[i].querySelector("summary");
        if (summary) {
            var parentPath = getParentText(details[i]).toUpperCase();
            var summaryPath = summary.textContent.trim().toUpperCase();
            var fullPath = parentPath + " " + summaryPath;
            
            // Highlight matching summaries
            if (fullPath.includes(filter)) {
                summary.style.background = '#eaeaea';
                 details[i].open = true;
                 
                  if (!firstMatchFound) {
                    summary.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
                    firstMatchFound = true;
                }
                 
                 // Open parent details elements recursively
                var parentDetails = details[i].parentNode;
                while (parentDetails.tagName === 'DETAILS') {
                    parentDetails.open = true;
                    parentDetails = parentDetails.parentNode;
                }
                
            } else {
                summary.style.background = '';
                 details[i].open = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
 
function getParentText(element) {
    var text = "";
    var parent = element.parentNode;
    while (parent && parent.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'details') {
        var summary = parent.querySelector("summary");
        if (summary) {
            text = summary.textContent.trim() + " " + text;
        }
        parent = parent.parentNode;
    }
    return text.trim();
}
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```